# Java initializing an integer and adding it to a list in one line

Tags: java

A tiny annoyance I have in my code right now - these two lines of code:

```
int i = 1;
listOfIntegers.add(i);
```

I would really like these to be one line but I can't for the life of me find anything like "new int[] {1}" or similar. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is, and it is as easy as possible :)

```
listOfIntegers.add(1);
```

PS : For primitive data types you dont have to create "instances" of them, they are instances itself.

Comment: oh. OH. Bloody of course. The actual number is not so much 1 as it is a integer returned by a method but I can just as easily just... yes. I feel a bit silly now, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Klaabu - that happens :D, btw : you can even store a results of expressions by same approach. For example `listOfIntegers.add(9-8);` do the same as `listOfIntegers.add(1);`

Comment: Note that this code is using the auto-boxing feature of Java (auto-converting int into Integer). This is fine, but it's important to know what is going on behind the scenes.  This article has some common gotchas: http://www.certpal.com/blogs/2009/08/autoboxing-unboxing-gotchas/